# Bookmark synchronization without using google sync

Tags: sync, bookmarks

I am using [Iridium](https://iridiumbrowser.de/), a chrome based browser. I would like to synchronize my bookmarks without using google sync (which is not enabled in Iridium).

I am open to installing plugins if needed. I have access to a personal shared hosting webserver and a dropbox.  I would prefer to **not** use a third party server for synchronization, but that's not an absolute limitation -- if that's the only option I will use it.

Comment: Does Iridium supper the latest features and policies that Chrome does? Chrome has this functionality built in. It’s called roaming profile support and you simply enable it and set the location of the roaming profile to a cloud synced folder on multiple machines. The entire chrome profile will sync between all the systems using the cloud enabled folder. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7349337?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Syncmarx](https://syncmarx.mcleodgaming.com/) will sync via your Dropbox. It's not as private as a personal server, but it's not google.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to take a look at [floccus](https://github.com/marcelklehr/floccus#readme) which is said to support any webDAV enabled servers in its recent version and can be manually installed on chrome based browsers.

Comment: My server doesn't support webDAV unfortunately. :(